# glVertexArrays, out of bounds. Invalid index

Tags: c, opengl

This is something interesting that I was looking into.

**varray.c:**

```
   static GLint vertices[] = {25, 25,
                       100, 325,
                       175, 25,
                       175, 325,
                       250, 25,
                       325, 325};
   glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glVertexPointer (2, GL_INT, 0, vertices);
```

This has 6 elements for vertices.
Now If I draw

```
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

It is workingn as expected.

Now if I give something like

```
glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 126);
```

I have asked glDrawArrays to draw 126 elements. Which are not present in the memory. 
How does OpenGL handle a situation like this ?

- Does it do some array calculations, and knows that it has 6 elements ? In that case it ignores the remaining 120 ?
- Or would it go on to draw junk ?

Comment: The title mentions `glVertexArrays`, while the question at hand concerns `glDrawArrays`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the 2<sup>nd</sup> call to `glDrawArrays()` runs into undefined behaviour as the function will try to read beyond `vertices`' s boundaries.

> Does it do some array calculations, and knows that it has 6 elements?

It cannot, as `vertices` decays to a C-pointer by being passed down to `glVertexPointer()`. From a C-pointer it is impossible to draw any information on how many allocated memory it is pointing to.

It's just bad luck the application doesn't crash.

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. It doesn't crash, but it just gives a perfect results. So, is there any way to catch programmers errors ?

Comment: @user2983543: Run the program doing such things using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) and see what is says.

Comment: I defined another array immediately after the first array (and appears int memory. But it does not display the junk, so apparently it does go through the program memory for the loop.

Comment: @user2983543: "*undefined behaviour*" does not necessarily means the program has to crash, but more or less everything could happen.